# How to delete an item from an array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array :

```
var menu_items = [];
```

I push two element in it like this :

```
 menu_items.push({
                    order: menu_items.length + 1, // value= 1
                    title: 'Label',
                    url: '',
                    IsSystemMenuItem: true
                });

 menu_items.push({
                    order: menu_items.length + 1, // value =2
                    title: 'grid',
                    url: '',
                    IsSystemMenuItem: true
                });
```

now i want to delete second item (i.e where  order: menu_items.length + 1, // value =2 and title: 'grid')

how can i delete this item ??

Answer (score 3):

Use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove an item :

```
delete menu_items[1];
```

But note that it lets a hole in your array.

If you want to have an array without hole, use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) :

```
menu_items.splice(1, 1);
```

If what you want is to remove elements based on their properties, then you could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```
menu_items = menu_items.filter(function(v) { return v.title!='grid' });
```

If you want to be more compatible, and as you use jQuery, you may also use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) :

```
menu_items = $.grep(menu_items, function(v) { return v.title!='grid' });
```

Comment: Delete won't remove the element from the array it will only set the element as undefined.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a note that `Array.filter` is IE9+

Comment: @Cerbrus You did it :) (btw the page I linked to contains a shim)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice()` for this.

```
menu_items.splice(1, 1);
```

The first parameter is the index of the element you want to delete. The second parameter is the number of elements you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
delete Your_items[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an item by title, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
function deleteItemByTitle(array, title){
    for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++){ // Loop through the array,
        if(array[i].title == title){              // If the correct element is found,
            array.splice(i, 1);                   // Remove the found element.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can just call the function:

```
deleteItemByTitle(myArray, "grid");
```

Replace `title` with `order`, if you want that to be the property to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete according to order number or similar. This is a basic example of how it would be done:

```
function DeleteFromArray(orderId)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < menu_items.length; i++)
    {
        if(menu_items[i].order === orderId) return menu_items.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Of course `menu_items[i].order === orderId` could be replaced by something like `menu_items[i].title === orderId` and then just change `orderId` to `orderTitle` or whatever floats your fancy.